# Extracting a substring based on conditions and adding into another column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like (`df.head(2)`):

| Country | Data |
| --- | --- |
| America | blahblahblah[@A , @b]blahblahblah |
| Cuba | blahblahblahblahblahblah[@f, @f]blahblahblah |

I would like to have a code where I am able to extract the group tags in the `Data` column. An example of an output is this:

| Country | Data | Group Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| America | blahblahblah[@A , @b]blahblahblah | [@A , @b] |
| Cuba | blahblahblahblahblahblah[@f, @f]blahblahblah | [@f , @f] |

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['America', 'Cuba'],
                   'Data': ['blahblahblah[@A , @b]blahblahblah',
                            'blahblahblahblahblahblah[@f, @f]blahblahblah']})
df['Group Tag'] = df['Data'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("["):st.find("]")+1])
df['Data'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['Data'].replace(str(row['Group Tag']), ''), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a function to extract the tag, you can achieve this with regex (python [re](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) module):

```
import re

def search_for_tag(s: str):
    groups = re.search(r"(\[.*\])", s).groups()
    return groups[0] if groups else None
```

It will return first found tag group or None if it can't find anything

Then use [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to extract values from the "Data" column:

```
values = df['Data'].apply(search_for_tag)
```

and then create a new column by assigning values to it

```
df['Data'] = values
```